# Does Drupal modify folder permissions during runtime?

Tags: files

Does Drupal modify the permissions on folder within the sites folder? Is there an edge case where this is possible outside of install?

I've been seeing an issue where a sites folder whether it be default or blah.com is getting it's write permissions removed after loading the site.

It's not specific to one codebase, it occurs across multiple codebases (no modifications to core) and across multiple versions 6/7.

This is problematic when using git with a specific site folder as git can no longer perform checkouts and merges without the write permissions.

Comment: Aside: The permissions model changes substantially in Drupal 8; this is still under discussion. See: http://drupal.org/node/1908440

Answer (score 2, accepted):

String `chmod` is found in 11 files in my Drupal 7.22 installation. Next 9 occurrences are found in Drush and Coder modules, and one in Examples for Developers module.

One of the files frequently turned read only is settings.php and it is done exactly to stop people from overwriting it with automatic tools.

Comment: Thanks, I've tracked down an edge case with prepareInstallDirectory thanks to this answer.

Answer (score 2):

Yes drupal modify `default` folder permission during runtime, and this folder is what exactly you should add it to your `.gitignore` because it contains user uploaded files which have not value to keeping in repository.